# Write simple unit test for isolated function in Golang, ethereum virtual machine

Tags: unit-testing, go, virtual-machine, ethereum

In this situation there isn't one correct answer, or expected result, that I can check for, I'm looking to evaluate the execution time of a function under different conditions, is that still a unit-test?

---

There's a function embedded in a project I'm working on that executes an addition operation (opAdd) on a virtual machine (the Ethereum VM), the file can be found [on the project GitHub page](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/instructions.go).

This is the specific function responsible for the task:

```
func opAdd(pc *uint64, evm *EVM, contract *Contract, memory *Memory, stack *Stack) ([]byte, error) {
    x, y := stack.pop(), stack.pop()
    stack.push(math.U256(x.Add(x, y)))

    evm.interpreter.intPool.put(y)

    return nil, nil
}
```

What I'd like to do is create a "*unit-test*" of sorts to evaluate the execution speed of this operation. To assess this I've modified the function accordingly:

```
func opAdd(pc *uint64, evm *EVM, contract *Contract, memory *Memory, stack *Stack) ([]byte, error) {

    // begin execution time tracking
    var startTime = time.Now().UnixNano();

    x, y := stack.pop(), stack.pop()
    stack.push(math.U256(x.Add(x, y)))

    evm.interpreter.intPool.put(y)

    // log ellapsed execution time
    fmt.Println("execute opAdd consume = ",(time.Now().UnixNano() - startTime))

    return nil, nil
}
```

However, what is missing is the ability to call this function in isolation, and feed it varying amounts of data such that I could evaluate the behaviour of this code under different conditions.

For instance I'd like to see how long it takes to execute with gigabytes, megabytes, etc.

There is some code to check the functioning of the vm [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/tests/vm_test.go), but it's too complicated for me to understand - I'm new to Golang.

What I'd like to do is write the simplest program possible that could invoke this function, taking as a parameter a varying amount of input data to process. Towards this end I've examined [multiple resources](https://blog.alexellis.io/golang-writing-unit-tests/), but if an experienced gopher could point me in the right direction it would be immeasurably valuable to advancing my understanding of how to construct practical unit tests.

Comment: Check out the 'Benchmarks' section for the [testing package](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/).

Comment: cool, thank you for your advice. I've been trying to grok that exact thing just now actually. Do you know what it might look like in this case? even in pseudocode for example

Comment: You will just need a `BenchmarkOpAdd` function where you setup your parameters to pass `opAdd` and then loop `b.N` times (as they do in the examples for the package linked earlier), calling opAdd in each iteration. If you want to test different conditions, just make separate `BenchmarkOpAddWithCertainCondition` functions and setup your parameters appropriately.

Comment: You might try posting this on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com